# Keeping track on Checkbox count in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to keep track of my checkbox count. i.e,  for example if i have 3 checkboxes 
Apples
Mangoes
Oranges
when i check on Apples check box, it should show the count as 1 next to the label, if i click oranges check box it should show it should show the count as 2. Now, if I uncheck Apples, now oranges count should become 1 and apples should become 0.

I have tried the following code :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="apples" id="fruits"/> Apples <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="mangoes" id="fruits"/> Mangoes <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="oranges" id="fruits"/> Oranges <br/>

<script>
var inputElems = document.getElementByTagname("input");
for (var i=0; i  &lt; inputElems.length; i++) {
                if (inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" &amp;&amp; inputElems[i].checked === true) 
                {
                    if(inputElems[i].id === "apple")
                    {
                    count1++;
                    count1 = count1+count2+count3;

                    alert('count for apples: '+count1);

                    }
                    if(inputElems[i].id === "mango")
                    {
                    count2++;
                    count2 = count1+count2+count3;
                    alert('count for mangoes: '+count2);
                    }
                    if(inputElems[i].id === "orange")
                    {
                    count3++;
                    count3 = count1+count2+count3;
                    alert('count for oranges: '+count3);
                    }
                }
                }
              }
```

Here, I have tried putting values in alert boxes. But I want to try putting it next to the label.
i.e:
Apples (1)
Mangoes (3)
Oranges (2)
like this according to the checkbox I select. How do I do that? Please help me.

Thanks,
Shruthi

Comment: Normally checkBox are used for true/false value, not as a button.

Comment: `id="fruits"` is wrong... use class instead.. IDs should be unique..

Comment: How do I print the count next to the label ??

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByTagname("input");` , it's `getElementsByTagName()`

`for (var i=0; i  &lt; inputElems.length; i++) {` , replace `$lt;` with `<`

`if (inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" &amp;&amp; inputElems[i].checked === true)`, replace `&amp;&amp;` with `&&`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="apples" id="fruits"/> Apples <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="mangoes" id="fruits"/> Mangoes <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="oranges" id="fruits"/> Oranges <br/>
```

all input types have `id ="fruits"`,which is wrong as id's should be unique and in your js your checking for "apples","oranges"... .Also add a onchange event to check whether the user checked a checkbox or not

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have done the above changes. Now, I want to print my count value next to the label. How do I do that?